# How to get middlemouse click event in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, click, mouseevent, onclicklistener

How can I respond to a middle mouse click in C++/OpenGL?

I know it may have to do with the `WM_MBUTTONDOWN` event however I am completely clueless with using it. I am also unfamiliar with callback functions so if it has to be used, can it be thoroughly explained? Can anyone show me how to implement the code for middle mouse click event?

Comment: If you're using OpenGL to any useful extent, you're probably already using a callback function.  Bascially, you hand OpenGL a pointer to one of your functions, and OpenGL *calls back* your function under certain circumstances.

Comment: Have you tried searching for [`opengl middle mouse button`](https://www.google.com/search?q=opengl+middle+mouse+button)? I'm finding many useful results. Particularly if you're using [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/).

Comment: `WM_MBUTTONDOWN` is part of the Windows API, and not C++ or OpenGL, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and implement the oldschool version with the `WM_` commands, but I think it'll be a lot easier to use **[GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html)** (since it *really* makes life with OpenGL easier).

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
void myMouseHandleFunction(int button, int state, int x, int y){
   if(button==GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN) std::cout << "Pressed middle mouse button!";
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
   glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
   glutInitWindowPosition(300, 200);
   glutCreateWindow("Hello World!");
   glutMouseFunc(myMouseHandleFunction);
   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
}
```

If you're doing a simple app, GLUT will be sufficient. If you wanna do something more complicated, try [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) or [openglut](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/). The old, basic GLUT doesn't handle the **mouse wheel**, so if you want to check for that - you'll need one of those two.

Comment: OK so could you explain me this though, you create myMouseHandleFunction with four parameters and pass this function as a parameter to glutMouseFunc. Is this it? Does the four parameters (int button, int state, int x, int y) get retrieved automatically without me explicitly setting them in main? How does all this work?

Comment: Yes, GLUT takes care of setting those parameters for you. The function will get called everytime you press/release a mouse button, automatically. This is it :)

Comment: Can I by any chance still call glutMouseFunc(myMouseHandleFunction); without glutInit(&argc, argv);
and all of those Init functions? They are conflicting with the program that is at its current state. Is it possible to call  glutMouseFunc and avoid any errors?

Comment: Because I seem to be getting Access violation reading location 0x000000b0 right where the glutMouseFunc(myMouseHandleFunction); is placed.

Comment: You have to have at least `glutInit` and `glutMainLoop` as far as I know. The mouse is handled __after__ your app enters `glutMainLoop`. If you would edit the first post and add info about why you can't use GLUT (so talk about the conflicts), maybe I would be able to help more.